# How to setup laravel in this url format http://ip-address/~username

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.4

I had setup Laravel projects before but this is my first time setting it up on this url format: http://ip-address/~username.

When I first visited the url, it just shows the directory listing so I tried accessing it by appending `/public` in the url and it works. However all the other links have `/public` on it and leads to a `404` error.

This is the current directory structure:

```
inside public_html
- app
- bootstrap
- config
- database
- public
- other folders
- htaccess
- other files
```

I tried putting an `htaccess` file in the project root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On 

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However it still doesn't work and I don't know what to do anymore. If you have been in this kind of situation before, please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your WebServer's document root to the public directory, that way it looks in the public and you wont have to append your url with public all the time.

Either that or you'll have to move your index.php out of the public directory and put it inside the root directory your web server is currently set as, but I would recommend you do the first option.

Comment: The first option, I've done that before but only on localhost. I don't know how to do it in the production server. Can you give me an example on how to do it? Currently searching for that solution.

Comment: Of course, could you just tell me what Web Server you're actually using? From your original question I guess you're using xampp?

Comment: Thanks, it's apache on centos. It's not on localhost so I'm not using xampp.

Comment: Instructions to change a document root can be found here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/337874/change-apache-document-root-folder-to-secondary-hard-drive/421214